# How can i create: if window.location.origin is not this and screen resolutions is this then redirect url? with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a script that says if the window.location.origin is no equal to "http://www.mymobilesite.com" and the screen resolution is less than or equal to 600 then redirect to "http://www.mymobilesite.com"

I have been able to create each statement separately but still learning and when I go to combine them with && I get stuck. I can get it to redirect to mymobilesite.com but it still redirects even if the origin is mymobilesite.com 
Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Here is what I have been working on:

```
if ((window.location.origin != "http://www.mymobilesite.com") && ($(window).width() <= 600)) {
location.href = "http://www.mymobilesite.com"
}
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, screen width. What I mainly need help with how to say if both of those statements are true then redirect to mymobilesite.com

Comment: You did that part correctly in the code above, as far as I can tell. You might have a problem with the `www.` subdomain, though; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like you're trying to determine whether a user is on a mobile device, why not find out the navigator's `userAgent` via regex:

```
var notSite = window.location.origin !== "http://razmobile.com.com";
var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if (notSite && isMobile) {
  window.location.href = "http://www.mymobilesite.com";
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/3046413

Comment: Thank you for your help but this does not appear to work from my mobile. If I go to mymobilesite on a desktop then go to the site main site i am not redirected back to mymobilesite however if i go to main site on my mobile device i am taken to mymobilesite but when i click to go to the main site and click to go to the full version i am still redirected back to the mobile site.

Comment: Thanks again for your work but the update does not appear to redirect at all.

Comment: Let me start from scratch. What does my most recent code give you?

Comment: The latest code does not redirect from a mobile device, it does redirect from a desktop but when clicking to return to the PC view I am directed back to the mobile.

Comment: i dont think this makes a  difference but the mobile site is at http://razmobile.com so there is no www.

Comment: Since your basically just testing whether you're on a mobile device, why not find navigator's user agent via regex. Let me know if my most recent answer works.

Comment: Thanks again, still seeing the same issue. I am taken to the mobile view when loading he page from my mobile but when i select PC view from the mobile view I am redirected back to mobile view.

Comment: Are you on your mobile device when you select to view on desktop?

Comment: Yes, I am on a mobile

Comment: So hypothetically it's doing what it's supposed to do: detecting if you're on a desktop/mobile device. Since you're on a mobile device it won't take you to desktop because you're not on desktop. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions given already about using `screen.width` instead of jQuery, you could use regular expressions to make the redirect work whether or not you're using the `www.` subdomain of `mymobilewebsite.com`.

```
if (!/mymobilewebsite\.com$/.test(location.host) && screen.width <= 600) {
    location.href = "http://www.mymobilesite.com"
}
```